# How can I enforce VS to include the assemblies used in GAC to be copied to the output folder?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, deployment, assemblies, gac

I have installed OpenXML SDK to my development machine and it registered the relevant assemlies to GAC as far as I can see. (For example:  DocumentFormat.OpenXml)

I developed a console app.

But the thing is I want to deploy this app on a server where there is no OpenXML SDK installed.

**QUESTION**:
How can I enforce Visual Studio to include the assemblies used in GAC to be copied to the output folder?
(or should I find those assemblies and take a copy of them side by side with the console app's output folder instead?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I do this:

1. Mark those references as `Copy Local = true`. This puts the dlls in the bin folder after a build.

That might be enough for you, but I do these following steps if I want to add those to source control so that other devs/build servers can find the assemblies:

1. Then move them from the bin to some other folder in your solution.
2. Remove the original reference.
3. Add a new reference to the new location you have copied to.

It's pretty much the same as the solution you were going to do, but the `Copy Local` step helps you find the exact `dll` that is being used rather than hunt around the GAC.

Answer (score 1):

[image: View in Visual Studio]

I had this issue before, you need to look at the properties of the assembly and find a property called 'Copy to output directory' and select 'Copy always'. It is probably set to 'Do not copy'. Something like that, took me a while to figure it out but when you build and deploy the project, it includes the references in the output folder.

EDIT: Right click the .dll in Visual Studio and click properties, second option down will be 'Copy to output directory'